# Bean interface and Bean implementation in different projects

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi, jboss-weld

Is it possible to have a bean interface in a project and the implementation of that bean in another project that includes the previous project as a dependency?

I have the following interface:

```
package com.proj1.util;
import .....;

public interface Notification {

   addNotification();
   addError();    

}
```

In the same project (i.e. Proj1) I have also the following class:

```
package com.proj1.util.exception;
import .....;

public class ExceptionHandler extends RuntimeException ... {
   private String errorMessage;

   @Override
   public void handle() {
      Util.getBeanInstance(Notification.class).addError(errorMessage);
   }    

}
```

Now in the second project I have the actual implementation of `Notification` that is as follows:

```
package com.proj2.beans;

@Named
@ConversationScoped
public class NotificationBean implements Notification, Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    ...
}
```

This situation leads to an exception in Tomcat with the message "**WebBeans context with scope type annotation @ConversationScoped does not exist within current thread**"

My proposal was to add a Factory that produces my NotificationBean but it doesn't seem to change much.

```
package com.proj2.beans.cdi;

import javax.enterprise.inject.New;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;

import com.proj1.util.Notification;

public class NotificationBeanFactory {

    @Produces
    public Notification create(@New NotificationBean notificationBean) {
        return notificationBean;
    }
}
```

The question is how can I use a bean in a project in which I have only it's interface while the bean implementation is in another project. Is it possible?

Comment: Exception suggests that the thread in question (the one wherein the attempt is made to obtain the bean) isn't a HTTP request thread. In other words, HTTP related scopes such as HTTP conversation and HTTP session are unavailable. Is this true? Why exactly is it `@ConversationScoped` then? Where exactly did you expect the container to store the actual bean instance?

Comment: It's a JSF application the request is made from the browser so it is an HTTP request. Though probably it's because no conversation has yet begun. The `NotificationBean` actually should manage my messages (Errors, Warnings and so on) for all my application. Would it be more wise to make it session scoped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception suggests there is no running conversation so I would start by determining when do you attempt to use `@ConversationScoped` bean and from which class.

Your code pieces indicate that `ExceptionHandler` class calls a magical formula which we do not know anything else about:

```
Util.getBeanInstance(Notification.class).add(...);
```

Trying to use this when there is no active conversation might lead to the exception you see. Therefore you could `@Inject ExceptionHandler` into `NotificationBean` so that you only ever use it while there is active conversation.

As for the Weld question regarding interface and impl in different projects; it is possible. in your `proj2` Weld will simply identify a bean `NotificationBean` and amongst it's types there will also be `Notification` hence you can then `@Inject Notification`.
It might not work the other way round though - in `proj1` you cannot `@Inject Notification` because `proj1` itself does not have any bean which would implement that interface.

Comment: `Util.getBeanInstance(...)` is a set of utility methods I've built that use BeanManager to get beans and return the requested bean.
In fact the whole design works unless there's no conversation opened. And that is exactly what's happening because My application is failing before opening a certain conversation and tries to output an error message notification.